# Add an application to windows startup visual forum applcation

Tags: c++, forum

I have a problem. I want to add an application to windows startup. I am making visual express 2010 forum application.

I want to add an application in the path "C:\app\trial.exe" to my windows startup.

```
    const char path[]="C:\\app\\trial.exe";
    HKEY hkey;
    long regOpenResult;

    regOpenResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,(LPCWSTR)"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0L,KEY_WRITE, &hkey);

         if (ERROR_SUCCESS == regOpenResult){
         RegSetValueEx(hkey,(LPCWSTR)"startup sample",0,REG_SZ,(BYTE*) path, strlen(path));
             if( ERROR_SUCCESS == regOpenResult )

                MessageBox::Show("successfully added to start up");
             else
                MessageBox::Show("1. Failed to set at startup");
             }
         else
            MessageBox::Show("2. Failed to set at startup");
         RegCloseKey(hkey);
```

I used the following code by adding 'Windows.h' and 'advapi32.lib'.

But i always shows the message    "2. Failed to set at startup"

What is the wrong with this code.
Can i use any other form of code in forum application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your program running with Administrator rights?

Comment: yes. it show Administrator on the top